# Cannot get the output of pstats

Tags: python

I'm trying to use `cProfile` from: https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile

I can get the data to print but I want to be able to manipulate the data and sort so that I get just the info I want. To get the data to print I use:

```
b = cProfile.run("function_name")
```

But after that runs and prints, `b = None` and I cannot figure out where the data is that it printed so that I can manipulate the data.  Of course, I can see the data, but in order to analyze the data I need to able to get some sort of output into my IED editor. I've tried pstats but I get error messages. It seems that to use pstats I have to save some sort of file but I cannot figure out how to run the program and save it to a file.

UPDATE:

I almost have a solution

```
cProfile.run('re.compile("foo|bar")', 'restats')
```

There is a second argument where you can save a file as 'restats'.  Now I should be able to open it and read it.

SOLVED:

```
cProfile.run("get_result()", 'data_stats')
p = pstats.Stats('data_stats')
p.strip_dirs().sort_stats(-1).print_stats()
p.sort_stats('name')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
cProfile.run("get_result()", 'data_stats')
p = pstats.Stats('data_stats')
p.strip_dirs().sort_stats(-1).print_stats()
p.sort_stats('name')
```

In addition to the first argument which runs the code, the second argument actually saves the output to a file.  The next line will then open the file.  Once that file is open you should be able to see the values of p in your IED editor and be able to use normal python operations to manipulate it.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: All i get when i run `p.print_stats()` is some `<pstats.Stats oobject at 0x00...>` which is useles. how to fixthis?